# Working with a Passive PS/2 to USB converter

Tags: usb, ps2

For some background see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/825714/ps-2-mouse-with-ps-2-to-usb-adaptor-not-working) question.
I've recently gotten my hand on a logitech Y-ST39 keyboard which uses the PS/2 protocel. I've bought an converter for it without knowing that it is a passive converter instead of an active one. Therefor it doesn't work when I plug it into a modern computer. I could of course fix this by just buying an active adapter, but it has gotten my curious. Is there any way to take the signal I'm currently getting (PS/2 protocol) and make it usable on my computer. Maybe by writing some software, or is this sorta stuff locked behind the firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some hardware to connect up the clock and data lines to, and then some software which implements the protocol.

Modern PCs don't have this kind of hardware, and you can't use the USB port for it, because the USB controller only understands USB.

Embedded computers like the RaspPi do (if add a voltage converter), but then it may be easier to just buy an active converter...

Details about the PS/2 protocol are easy to find, google. Projects of people who built their own PS/2 active adapter using various kinds of hardware are also easy to find.