# P300STD barcode scanner not printing with ps2 to usb adaptor

Tags: usb, ps2

my barcode scanner is not recognized when using ps2 to  usb adapter ,
i had to use an adaptater as my pc hasn't any ps2 port it makes a bip sound but nothing is displayed in Notepad i am using windows 10

Comment: Those adaptors are only for mice and keyboards that already know how to work over either PS2 or USB. They don't work for making an old PS2 only device work over USB.

Comment: it works with a pc with ps2 but when using the adapter it doesn't work ,are yu saying i can't do it? i was thinking about a driver' s issue ....

Comment: and what about keyboard wedge software?

Comment: You will either have to upgrade the scanner or add a ps2 card into the PC if it is a desktop.

Comment: The key queston here is: What do you call a 'ps2 to usb adapter'. If it is a small convertor plug then pleaser read this post: https://superuser.com/questions/825714/ps-2-mouse-with-ps-2-to-usb-adaptor-not-working